# Oracle SQL Constraint with IF condition

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I need create a constraint with this condition If column_1 = 'Y' then column_2 is not null. I need make the column_2 not null if column_1 is equal 'Y'. In other cases you can insert or not values in column_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express this as:

```
check (column_1 <> 'Y' or column_2 is not null)
```

Note:  This version assumes that `column_1` is not `NULL`, but the logic can easily be adjusted to handle that.

Or, alternatively:

```
check (not (column_1 = 'Y' and column_2 is null) )
```